# Is there any way to broadcast kafka message to all partitions?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have use case to broadcast specific type of message to all partitions. I explored on custom partitioner but it doesn't support broadcast to all partitions. I am using custom partitioner to forward other type of messages to specific partitioner.

1. I want to know is there any way from kafka side to support broadcasting to all partitions?
2. Ideas around custom solutions are also welcome:-
   One of the way is to have separate kafka producer instance to send message to all partitions individually but if number of partitions are more and number of broadcasting messages are more then that can become bottleneck or might have latency overhead. Using kafka streams or kafka producer.

```
Producer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(props);
 for (int partition = 0; part < totalNoOfPartitions; partition++)
     producer.send(new ProducerRecord<String, String>("Test", partition, "Hello", "World!"));

 producer.close();
```

I understand duplicating data can be concern here but let's ignore that factor here. We are fine with duplicate data on kafka cluster.
**Please help if there is better way than what is proposed in this post.**

Comment: Can you explain your use-case better? Specifically, how are you consuming the messages?

Comment: @OneCricketeer We work in financial domain. There are certain events required for all consumers for example when there is Dividend declared on some share, this event is something common to all consumers processor. Each consumer subscribe to one partition and process specific book. Custom partitioner publish events specific to that book on that partition. In short, custom partitioner is book aware partitioner.

I hope this explanation is enough. Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Since consumers can assign themselves to select partitions, then what's the point of publishing to all partitions? Note that the default behavior of a single consumer group will prevent more than one consumer from reading from any partition. Plus, the code you've shown is the only way to produce to all partitions at once. (Stream API will not help with this either)

Comment: @OneCricketeer Can calling `forward()` method number of times as number of partitions and passing partition Id as key with Custom Partitioner. Will this work?

Comment: I haven't ever tried to forward more than one record at a time, but if they have different keys, then it might work

Comment: @OneCricketeer
I tried and it is working. I configure exactly once delivery setting for my app, Will it guarantee exactly once even if I call ```forward()``` method for each partition.

Comment: I don't see why not. Kafka Streams is just a layer over the regular producer api methods

Answer (score 0):

In older version of Kafka, it's not easily possible to do. You would need to "replicate" the message manually inside your Kafka Streams application, and send each copy to a different partition using a custom partitioner.

In the upcoming **Kafka 3.4** release, there will be built-in support to mulit-cast/broadcast a message to multiple partitions via [KIP-837](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=211883356). The `StreamPartitioner` interface now has a new method `Optional<Set<Integer>> partitions(String topic, K key, V value, int numPartitions)` that allows you to return a set of partitions you want a single record to be written into (instead of a single partition as in the old interface).

Comment: Thanks for updating here. Great to know this. Waiting for Kafka 3.4.